# Hot to synchronize files creation between multiple processes?

Tags: java, file, process, synchronization

i have robotframework plugin which may run several processes simultaneously, but the problem is that it create screenshots and one process may rewrite already taken screenshot from another process
i did such thing

```
File path;
while (true) {
    path = new File(logdir, normalizeFilename(filename));
    if (path.exists())
        continue;
    try {
        path.createNewFile();
        break;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

but i'm not sure it's enough, as long as i have only 2 processes there is no problem, but there may be more, and path.createNewFile(); doesn't give any error when there is already fail available, there is not much chance that after path.exists() return false there will be created same file because of timestamp in the name, but still i think there might be a problem and i don't know hot to synchronize  processes.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to give each of the processes a unique number when you start them, as an argument perhaps? If so, you'll be able to use that inside each process and write files like "name.1.timestamp.ext", "name.2.timestamp.ext"... So no process's file is actually named like an existing one.

Comment: this code is inside plugin which overrides methods in third party framework, i don't want to change framework code to pass arguments to my plugin